# AX 4.0: Create sales order from sales quotation with X++

Tags: axapta, x++

How can I, with X++, create a sales order from a sales quotation in AX 4.0? I've searched and found the same answer several places, however it seems to be specific to newer versions of AX.

This is what I've found here: https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/mafsarkhan/archive/2014/04/14/create-sales-order-from-sales-quotation

```
    static void createSalesOrderFromQuote(Args _args)
{
    SalesQuotationTable             salesQuotationTable = SalesQuotationTable::find("");
    SalesQuotationEditLinesForm     editLinesForm;
    ParmId                          parmId;

    editLinesForm = SalesQuotationEditLinesForm::construct(DocumentStatus::Confirmation);

    parmId = editLinesForm.parmId();

    editLinesForm.initParmSalesQuotationTable(salesQuotationTable);    
    editLinesForm.parmTransDate(systemDateGet());
    editLinesForm.prePromptInit();
    editLinesForm.initParameters(NoYes::No, NoYes::No, NoYes::No, NoYes::No, NoYes::No, '', NoYes::No); 

    editLinesForm.run();
}
```

The line `editLinesForm.prePromptInit();` wont compile and I guess that is due to only being available in newer versions. I can comment it out and the code will compile and run. However, even though I've added the ID of the `SalesQuotationTable` like this: `... ::find("123456")` It's seems the code converts ALL my quotations to `salesorders`, however I've yet to confirm this as I've been forced to kill the process to start working again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may comment out the call to `editLinesForm.prePromptInit()` from your method.
In order to not post all quotations into sales orders I would try to reproduce the `main()` method of the SalesQuotationEditLinesForm class in your system, omitting the logic related to datasource.
If I refer to my system I think your code might be missing:

```
editLinesForm.getLast();
editLinesForm.parmId(parmId);
```

before calling `editLinesForm.run()`